# Altering lytebox/lyteframe width and height properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using lytebox's lyteframe plugin to display a html form, at present time I can only specify the width and height of the content loaded into the frame as pixels, is there a method of setting these properties to display as the same width and height of the content that is loaded into the box?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `iframe` to display the HTML content, as it's demonstrated on their website, then the only way to do it involves Javascript - not CSS.

There's a solution for it posted here --> [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)