# jquery - is not a function error

Tags: jquery, function

Here is my code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.pluginbutton = function (options) {
        myoptions = $.extend({ left: true });
        return this.each(function () {
            var focus = false;
            if (focus === false) {
                this.hover(function () {
                    this.animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 -30px" }, { duration: 0 });
                    this.removeClass('VBfocus').addClass('VBHover');
                }, function () {
                    this.animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 0" }, { duration: 0 });
                    this.removeClass('VBfocus').removeClass('VBHover');
                });
            }
            this.mousedown(function () {
                focus = true
                this.animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 30px" }, { duration: 0 });
                this.addClass('VBfocus').removeClass('VBHover');
            }, function () {
                focus = false;
                this.animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 0" }, { duration: 0 });
                this.removeClass('VBfocus').addClass('VBHover');
            });
        });
    }
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.smallTabsHeader a').pluginbutton();
});
```

It gives me an error.  What's wrong?

Comment: What and where is the exact error?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This problem is "best" solved by using an [**anonymous function**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions) to pass-in the jQuery object thusly:

**The Anonymous Function Looks Like:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        // You pass-in jQuery and then alias it with the $-sign
        // So your internal code doesn't change
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This is JavaScript's method of implementing (poor man's) 'Dependency Injection' when used alongside things like the 'Module Pattern'.

**So Your Code Would Look Like:**
Of course, you might want to make some changes to your internal code now, but you get the idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $.fn.pluginbutton = function(options) {
            myoptions = $.extend({ left: true });
            return this.each(function() {
                var focus = false;
                if (focus === false) {
                    this.hover(function() {
                        this.animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 -30px" }, { duration: 0 });
                        this.removeClass('VBfocus').addClass('VBHover');
                    }, function() {
                        this.animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 0" }, { duration: 0 });
                        this.removeClass('VBfocus').removeClass('VBHover');
                    });
                }
                this.mousedown(function() {
                    focus = true
                    this.animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 30px" }, { duration: 0 });
                    this.addClass('VBfocus').removeClass('VBHover');
                }, function() {
                    focus = false;
                    this.animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 0" }, { duration: 0 });
                    this.removeClass('VBfocus').addClass('VBHover');
                });
            });
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem arises when a different system grabs the $ variable.  You have multiple $ variables being used as objects from multiple libraries, resulting in the error.

To solve it, use [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) just before your `(function($){`:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
$.fn.pluginbutton = function (options) {
...
```

Comment: fire fox returns $(".smallTabsHeader a").pluginbutton is not a function

Comment: the above causes massive amounts of errors throughout the page

Comment: I thought you mentioned "Jquery is not a function". Please edit your question's title and remove jquery from the title. It belongs to tags section.

Comment: I thought with no-conflict mode, you started with something like `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`. Then wherever you would have normally used `$(...)` you would use `$j(...)`. I don't know how else it would resolve conflicts with other functions named `$`.

Comment: this is not the problem at all. The OP specifically handles that issue in his code. The problem is that the OP does not pass a reference to the jQuery object in his anonymous function (*nor does he invoke it*). (*..plus some additional wrong handling of `this`*)

Answer (score 10):

change

```
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.smallTabsHeader a').pluginbutton();
});
```

to

```
})(jQuery); //<-- ADD THIS


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.smallTabsHeader a').pluginbutton();
});
```

This is needed because, you need to call the anonymous function that you created with

```
(function($){
```

and notice that it expects an argument that it will use internally as `$`, so you need to pass a reference to the jQuery object.

Additionally, you will need to change all the `this.` to `$(this).`, except the first one, in which you do `return this.each`

In the first one (*where you do not need the `$()`*) it is because in the plugin body, `this` holds a reference to the jQuery object matching your selector, but anywhere deeper than that, `this` refers to the specific DOM element, so you need to wrap it in `$()`.

Full code at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/NXESk/

Answer (score 3):

It works on my case:

```
import * as JQuery from "jquery";
const $ = JQuery.default;
```

Comment: This is the right answer when using Webpack or React Create App updates released after approx. Feb 2018. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When converting an ASP.Net webform prototype to a MVC site I got these errors:

> TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function
>   $("#accordion").accordion(

---

> $('#dialog').dialog({
>   TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

It worked fine in the webforms. The problem/solution was this line in the _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment it out to see if the errors go away. Then fix it in the BundlesConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by renaming my function.

Changed

```
function editForm(value)
```

to

```
function editTheForm(value)
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: wtf? How is this possible?

Comment: Lo0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0L )))

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the same error had a much easier fix. Basically my function was in a .js file that was not included in the current aspx that was showing. All I needed was the include line.