# $.isNumeric is not a function?

Tags: jquery

I am including a jQuery file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

I am having a code like this:

```
if($.isNumeric(now))
{            
  alert("yes");
}
else
{
  alert("no");
}
```

But when I run this script get an error:

> ```
> $.isNumeric is not a function
> ```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Try using `jQuery.isNumeric(row)`.  If that works, do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6109983/1144176).  It is also possible that there is a conflict if you are using other JS libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function () { //your code goes here... });` Please refer to [jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more details.

Alternatively, you can simply place your code before the `</body>`.

Also, you might want to try to replace $ with `jQuery` and see if there'd be any conflicts in you javascript, e.g. `jQuery.isNumeric("-10");`

If it does turn out to be conflicts, you can add this line of code, `jQuery.noConflict();` at the beginning of your jQuery code. Please refer to [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for more details.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109847/jquery-is-not-a-function-error) on Stackoverflow which might also be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the JQuery script has loaded by using `document.ready` (or just make sure your script comes after the JQuery script tag).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var now = 1;
    alert($.isNumeric(now) ? "yes" : "no");
});
```

Second, make sure the JQuery source actually loaded correctly... maybe try the JQuery CDN.

```
<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
```