# Keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: $(...). is not a function"

Tags: jquery

Im not a jQuerywiz, but I keep getting the "Uncaught TypeError: $(...). is not a function" on jQueryscripts. I'm trying to understand why I get them.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shop.xeptor.se/fileupload/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shop.xeptor.se/fileupload/jquery.blackcalculator.src.js"></script>

<div class="calculator"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var langs = {value: 'Valor', clear: 'Limpar', backspace: 'Voltar'};
   $('.calculator').blackCalculator({
     type:'advanced',
     allowKeyboard:true,
     css:'styles/',
     language:langs
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Its a guess, Instead of $ try jQuery

Comment: Have you checked that blackcalculator is properly loaded? jQuery appears to have loaded fine, because you didn't get a `$ is not defined` error.

Comment: The two links are valid, although jQuery 1.7.2 is more than 3 years old (march 2012). Maybe an outdated jQuery version?

Comment: [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L16UWW18XbXTyddidEmU?p=preview) looks okay. Could it be something else? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Typical message when noConflict() is used

Comment: My console is giving me a **Blocked loading mixed active content** .. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)..

Comment: Would you show an exact error in console? or screenshot of console?, Would you share code of blackCalculator as well so that we can run the code

Answer (score 2):

Close your jQuery code to:

```
(function($) {
 ...
})(jQuery);
```

This function will pass-in the jQuery object, so the browser will know, that the dollar sign is an abbreviation for `jQuery`. Otherwise the dollar sign is a very favourite one, so in your case it's probably represents something else :-)

The same problem was already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109847/jquery-is-not-a-function-error).

Comment: I see it as a possible solution, so downvoters should explain whu it is not?!

Comment: Probably because I made a mistake while writing it, but I've corrected it almost imediatelly and then they didn't notice :D

Comment: I didn't downvote but IMO people is expecting some explanation besides this code. (what specific problem is this code potentially  solving)

Comment: This would only be a valid answer if jQuery was operating in no-conflict mode, and nothing in the question hints to that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi but we can presume OP didnt have posted all relevant code

Comment: @A.Wolff, in my experience, trying to second-guess the questioner usually does not result in the "right" answer. YMMV, though.

Comment: This also worked perfectly with some jQuery I have within my wordpress site code. Thank you @Eenoku!