# jQuery- plugin is not a function

Tags: jquery

I'm just learning to create jQuery plugin. But I'm getting error in my initial effort. I did refer here, [jquery - is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109847/jquery-is-not-a-function-error) but it seems like my code is similar to that. But what causing the above error?

//invoking the function like in app.js

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('body').testapp();
});
```

//defining the plugin in app.jquery.js

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
    $.fn.testapp = function(){
        return $(this).append('<h1>success</h1>');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

error getting in chrome console:

```
****app.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).testapp is not a function****
```

Comment: Did you call in the library prior to this? I get this when I forget to call the library

Comment: I did call jquery library prior to this..

Comment: Did you add Jquery in your project before calling you app?

Comment: @JoseOrtiz, sorry my bad, there were two jquery files included one before and jquery.min.js after my script..that causing the problm...now I included it before my script..and works fine

Comment: @JoseOrtiz, thank you so much for pointing out my silly mistake

Comment: No problem it happens to the best of us :) Happy coding