# Can't understand why this error(Uncaught TypeError: $(...).is(...).each is not a function) got on?

Tags: jquery

I was doing a simple code of appending the values of checkboxes and I encountered this error. It is a mystery for me why this error was shown. I have figured out the way to write it correctly but I would very much like to know why this error occurred? Tried the technique given in a question previously asked but it didn't work- [jquery - is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109847/jquery-is-not-a-function-error)

`Code with error:`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  
  $("#msg").html(" ");
  
   $("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked').each(function(){
   $("#msg").append(this.value);
   
   })
  }) 
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="mango">mango
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="apple">apple
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="cherry">cherry
<div id="msg"></div>
```

`Correct Code:`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  
  $("#msg").html(" ");
  
   $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
   $("#msg").append(this.value);
   
   })
  }) 
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="mango">mango
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="apple">apple
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="cherry">cherry
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: Anyway what do you think the `is` function returns? How do you expect that you would be able to call `each` on it?

Comment: is returns a `true` in my case

Comment: Then why do you think that a `true` has a member function `each`?

Comment: If I was all that proficient in jQuery, I wouldn't be asking questions out here.

Comment: Tips: Look up the documentation of jQuery when necessary instead of trying to memorizing everything.

Comment: @user202729 it would be helpful if you could atleast give a straight forward answer after downvoting me for I don't know what.

Comment: `$("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')` returns a Boolean (true/false). `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked")` returns a collection of jQuery elements that you can iterate over using `$.each`.

Comment: @connexo Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')` is a test that returns a Boolean (`true`/`false`). `true.each()` does not make sense, neither does `false.each()`.

`$("input[type='checkbox']:checked")` returns a *collection* of jQuery elements that you can iterate over using `$.each`.

Comment: I'd read that in the documentation but being a novice was not sure how to play around with it. Thanks a lot for all the help.