# How to reload wordpress page on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, anchor, page-refresh

Good day,

I am having a problem with reloading page when anchor link is clicked #about-us in wordpress site. If I hard code the link in wordpress header.php the page is reloading on anchor click e.g. `<a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>#about-us" onClick="window.location.reload(true);">`About us

But my problem comes when I want to use the link in wordpress menu, the page is not reloading on anchor click and I would like the page to load on anchor click. I have tried to add a javascript code into header.php but still the page doesn't refresh. JS code below:

```
<script>
$("#menu-item-2").on("click", function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.reload(true)
});
```

Please assist, Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you get any error in the console ?

Comment: I am getting the below error:

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Check the line of error if you can find something wrong

Comment: That means jQuery isn't loaded, or you need to use `jQuery` instead of the `$` alias. See [jquery - is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6109847/1264804).

Comment: Next time ask about the _actual_ problem, which was that error. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript is running before the node exists, it won't find the node thus won't bind to the click event.
Try wrapping your code into a load listener:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  $("#menu-item-2").on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.reload(true);
  });
});
</script>
```

Also, make sure jQuery is loaded if you use `$`

Here is a version without using jQuery at all:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.getElementById('menu-item-2').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.reload(true);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to understand before adding jQuery code in WordPress.

1. `$` is not a global jQuery variable in WordPress `jquery.js`, you will have to use the *jQuery* keyword to access global jQuery then you can use it as `$`
2. if you're putting jQuery code into `header.php` so make sure you add your `<script>...</script>` code after `wp_head();` line so that `jquery.js` could loader first and you could access `jQuery`.

So the correct Js code will look like this and you will have to put it after `wp_head();` in the `<head>` tag:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#menu-item-2").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.reload(true);
    });
});
```