# Embed Google Form in an iFrame with Auto Height Using a Code Block on Teachable

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms, iframe-resizer

I'm trying to get a Google form with dynamic/auto height embedded into a Code Block on a Teachable Lecture.

I tried this but it doesn't work: [Getting a Google Form in an IFrame with Auto Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819155/getting-a-google-form-in-an-iframe-with-auto-height)

Here is a Teachable support article on how to embed the Google Form, but it doesn't explain how to make the form auto height (dynamically adjust the height based on the length of the form so that there would be no scrolling within the iFrame): https://support.teachable.com/hc/en-us/articles/222637507-Embed-Forms-and-Other-Content-into-Lectures

If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

For cross domain iframes you need to be able to run JS code in both the iframe and the parent page for this to work. In the case of a Google form you will need to get Google to add this for you

Comment: Hi David, thanks for answering. I'm not sure what you mean. Can you tell me more? What are the steps you would take to get a link to an auto-height iFrame?