# Resizing an iframe height when the contents of the iframe change (same domain)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've been researching this for a few days and I'm stuck... I read this page:

[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

and this page:

[Auto resize iframe height when the height of the iframe contents change (same domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789198/auto-resize-iframe-height-when-the-height-of-the-iframe-contents-change-same-do)

It seems it's relatively easy to resize an iframe when the maine index.html that contains the iframes first loads, but once the iframe changes content I can't figure out how to re-size the iframe.

my index.html:

```
<body>
<iframe seamless frameborder="0" name="top" id="top" src="venues.php" width="100%" height="100" /></iframe>
<iframe seamless frameborder="0" name="main" id="main" src="admin.php" width="100%" height="2000" /></iframe>
```

When venues.php loads it's 100px (which is fine) but when somebody clisk in a (internal, same domain) link inside the venues.php page I need to resize the "top" frame height to fit the new contents.

I've tried a bunch of solutions I can always only get it resized on the first load but not when somebody clicks inside it.

Thanks

Comment: I've solved this using JS in the frame to send a message to JS in the container. The message says how big the frame needs to be, the JS in the container than resizes the control.

Comment: could you show me an example or at least tell me how you are sending the message to the container? I was under the impression (from things I read in one of those links) that you cannot communicate from the child to the parent

Comment: Have you had a look at:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082125/resize-iframe-on-content-refresh-or-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `mutation observer` event and the `postMessage API`, It's very difficult to create and implement script that can negotiate the dimension measurements of an iframe that frequently changes. I gave up on writing something from scratch and used this small plugin:

> https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

This **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfHvKfy2DjqVj9TqMsLe?p=preview)** demonstrates the use of this plugin when detecting the `mutation observer` event fire when resizing of the iframe happens.

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfHvKfy2DjqVj9TqMsLe?p=preview)

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at David Bradshaws git repo

He has developed a nice script to do what you are looking for.

> Keep same and cross domain iFrames sized to their content with support for >window/content resizing, in page links, nesting and multiple iFrames. >(Dependency free, IE8+) http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/

Comment: I have looked at Bradshaw's iFrame Resizer but couldn't get it to work... in fact in Chrome (locally) his test example did not even work for me

Comment: @marcnyc Try my demo, Chrome 51 tests just fine.