# Making iFrames dynamically resize heights

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I know a lot of people have asked this question and I've tried everything, but none of the solutions have worked for me.  I'm creating a front-end portal in ServiceNow and need to pull in multiple iframes of varying heights.  I would like the iframe heights to be dynamic based on the content.

I am using a method that seems to be pretty popular on this site:

```
<div class="grey"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="fluidMedia">
             <iframe src="my-page" frameborder="0" ></iframe>


            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

.fluidMedia {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* proportion value to aspect ratio 16:9 (9 / 16 = 0.5625 or 56.25%) */
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fluidMedia iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

After trying this, I still have to scroll on my iframe as seen in my screenshot:

[image: iframe issue screenshot]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are all of these iframes on the same domain as the main page(i.e. the page that contains these iframes)?

Comment: Anyways, check my answer out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37753146/2813224), If it helps you, upvote it, if it doesn't post a comment and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I'm using an autoresize but in jquery, if is not a problema doing this autoresize in jquery i can share it, let me know.

Comment: @grec0o, i woudn't mind taking a look at it and see if I can apply it.  At this point I'm willing to try anything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Then try something like that. First add an ID and a onload to your iframe, like that:

Library

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<iframe src="my-page" frameborder="0" id="foo" onload="autoResize('foo')"></iframe>
```

And here we go with the script.

```
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height=(newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width=(newwidth) + "px"; 
}
```

Test it and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: you added also the library? I edit the code and I add the library, just add it in the head.

Comment: yea, i added the library, but it's still not working...In my code above, does it matter that I've put the FluidMedia div and iframe within three other divs?

Comment: no, there shoul'd not be a problem, test it with a simple iframe inside a div