# How to adjust height of table td based on form within iframe height

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="mainform">
      <iframe id="ifSur"></iframe>
    </td>
    <td id="subform"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In iframe the `1.aspx` page will be loaded. So the height of `subform` `t`d must be  the height of `<form>` tag in `1.aspx`.

Comment: This stack post will probably help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Answer (score 0):

In 1.aspx's load event, call a function on the parent frame, passing the form height.

```
window.parent.adjustTD(document.myForm.offsetHeight);
```

(I'm assuming the form's name is "myForm"; if not, adjust the code accordingly.) On the parent:

```
function adjustTD(inHeight)
{
   document.getElementById("subform").style.height = inHeight.toString() + "px";
}
```

Untested code, may require debugging, etc., etc. Are you sure its "subform" you want to adjust, and not "mainform"?