# How to get height of iframe from its source

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
<iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" width="200" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://localhost/Widget/"></iframe>
```

I want to find the height of this iframe from the page `http://localhost/Widget/` using JavaScript.

Is there any way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: unsafe javascript attempt if iframe violates same origin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Answer (score 2):

I go a different way about the problem in my own solution:
Within the iframe I have:

```
<body onload="parent.setsize(document.body.scrollHeight);">
```

In the parent I have a js function:

```
function setsize(pixels){ 
if(navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") pixels+=40;
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1) pixels+=40;
document.getElementById('produktet').style.height=pixels+"px";
```

As you can see the total height of the iframe content is: document.body.scrollHeight

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get the "parent" first to do so. You can get the parent by `document.parent`, so the following should work (not tested):

```
parent.getElementById( 'frame1' ).getAttribute( 'height' );
```

If you've loaded jQuery in the parent, you might use that:

```
parent.jQuery('#frame1').attr('height');
```

**EDIT**: Do note however, that there is a security restriction in play here: both pages have to be on the same domain for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

To bypass cross origin issues. You can read the height before the body loads:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        var iframeSize = Math.max( document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                                   document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
                                   document.documentElement.offsetHeight );
    </script> 
  </head>
<body>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#frame1').attr('height');
```

using jQuery. Or

```
document.getElementbyId('frame1').getAttribute('height');
```

with plain js.