# iframe not resizing to content height

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have been trying to get this to work for a while but to no avail. ive tried various scripts but im clearly doing something wrong :(

I have a menu on the left of the page, which contain (same server) href links of which their target is an iframe on the right of the page.

it sends the page to the iframe fine, but the iframe height does not change.

Can someone please assist me :(

here is my code:

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.pageslide.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function sizeIframeToContent(id) {
    // resize iframe to be the height of the content
    try {
        var frame = document.getElementById(viewcontent);
        innerDoc = (frame.contentDocument) ?
                   frame.contentDocument : frame.contentWindow.document;
        var objToResize = (frame.style) ? frame.style : frame;
        objToResize.height = innerDoc.body.scrollHeight + 10 + 'px';
        //objToResize.width = innerDoc.body.scrollWidth + 10 + 'px';
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}
```

.... menu link

```
<div class="menuOut" onMouseOver="this.className='menuIn'" onMouseOut="this.className='menuOut'">
          <a href="forum_frame.php?forum=guest" target="viewcontent">- Forum Adverts </a></div>
```

.... iframe html

```
<div id=maincontain>
<iframe id="viewcontent" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#maincontain {
    width: 85%;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 12%;
}
#viewcontent {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    float: none;
}
```

The iframe just stays about 300px height unless I specify a bigger height manually.

the pages being loaded in, all have 800px+ heights.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a JSFiddle?

Comment: ... and why this question is in the jquery tag?

Answer (score 0):

The iframes' height is not influenced by the content. That's how iframes work.
If you need to shrink or grow them, you need to do that manually. Read more here:

- http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/iframe-height-scrollbar-example/
- http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/how_to_adjust_an_iframe_elements_height_to_fit_its_content/

Comment: so what is the best way to achieve what I want to do?
I simply have 1 page, default.php, with a menu down the left side and a big iframe on the right.

when I click a link in the menu, it sends it to the iframe. I just want that iframe to be the size of the page I clicked. :\

If im going the hard way about it, what is the best method to use?

Comment: @user1953045 The article in the second link completely explains what you need to do, along with the code ready to be pasted. It's a 10 minute read.

Comment: I read the article completely. Its similar to many others ive read today.
I followed it exactly, but it still wont work.

Im obviously doing something wrong. Im probably going to give up to be honest and look at a alternative method. its frustrating as there is no reason why it shouldnt work.

Comment: Ok,

I added a src=etc.xxx to the iframe tags and when I refresh my page, the iframe is resizing to the size of the source page.

When I click another link, it dont resize,

Comment: @user1953045 Maybe because you can no longer rely on iframe's `load` handler. Try to destroy and then recreate the iframe with the desired `src` on click (no `target` necessary as you'll be handling the clicks).

Comment: yeah, I sort of get that now. after realising that the scripts are working, I know I need to find a way to change the SRC and 'refresh' the iframe within the main page (without refreshing the whole page)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JQuery?

You could use:

```
$("#viewcontent").height($("#viewcontent").contents().find("html").height());
```

And just call that on whatever event you want the iframe to resize on. I've got it working on keyup for one of my own projects. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maddest_march_hare/ume3v/3/).

Answer (score 0):

**Please try the below script:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
//-->
</script>

<iframe src="test.html" width="100%" height="200px" id="my_frame" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('my_frame');"></iframe>
```

you Should have the source file with in your domain.this is already discussed 
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

for Cross Domain iframe Resizing please 
Click [here](http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/)