# Yet another iframe height issue

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, joomla

I have a Joomla website where I have a Direction map that is skinned with a mask (png). Everything is made in an external html document so I call it in an iFrame... So now when I load it in my joomla page it obviously did not show the directions since the iFrame do not resize its height dynamically. Unless I use a Scrolling bar, but I do not want one...

Here is my iframe code:

```
<iframe id="blockrandom" src="images/directionmapfr/map.html" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="700"></iframe>
```

I know that question have been asked before but nothing worked for me  and I am a Javascript noob so if someone have a good solution and is cool enough to share with me, I would be really happy...

So my main question is:
Is it possible to get an iframe containing a google map to auto resize its height when it show the directions? Without scrollbar of course and in a joomla module or article...

what I have tried so far:

Many example on this site about dynamic iframe resizing using script, jquery, CSS...
such as theses: [iFrame dynamic resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902258/iframe-dynamic-resize)
[Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Also i tried this:
http://www.minitek.gr/blog/coding/javascript/how-to-create-an-iframe-wrapper-in-joomla-with-dynamic-height

thanks

Comment: First of all, what exactly is your question? Also, please supply all your code in your question, don't link to your website. Also explain what you already tried.

Comment: I tried to post my entire code but failed to do so. Anyway I have updated my question to make it "clearer". Is it ok?

Comment: So are you saying that the height of the gogole maps page increases when it shows directions? And you want to resize the iframe to match this height?

Comment: Yes, when Google map display my directions result in the bottom panel, I would like my iFrame to expand to show the directions. Right now, if I set Scrolling="no" I can't see the entire directions since I can not scroll... I wish that the iFrame expand dynamically to show the entire result instead of using a scroll bar. I know that its complicated since I get the data from a different domain...