# Adjust Iframe height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Is there any method available to adjust the height of an iframe (which loads an external site)   dynamically ?

OR

is there any way to check whether if  the iframe has a scroll-bar present ?

Comment: I believe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes , but nothing is working for me . I am trying to load the document from an external site :(

Comment: Since you can not access anything when the iframe is from another domain, this will only work if the remote site is “helping” you – like Facebook does for canvas/page tab apps f.e., they do some cross-domain communication so that the iframed page sends its own height to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Get the iFrame jQuery Object
var $MyFrame = $("#iframeid");

// You need to wait for the iFrame content to load first
// So, that the click events work properly
$MyFrame.load(function () {
    var frameBody = $MyFrame.contents().find('body');

    // Set the iFrame height
    $MyFrame.css({
        height: frameBody.outerHeight()
    });
});
```