# Resize iframe after content height changes

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-plugins, postmessage

i'm using [Iframe Height Jquery Plugin (Version 1.2.1)](https://github.com/Sly777/Iframe-Height-Jquery-Plugin) to re-size an iframe with dynamic contents.

The iframe re-sizes correctly when it's loaded. Now i got some ui-tabs in the content, with different heights and i want to resize the iframe when a tab is selected.

Calling again jQuery.iframeHeightExternal(); in the iframe content returns only undefined and nothing happens.

Calling again jQuery('#iframe-box').iframeHeight(); in the top-frame resizes correctly. But i need it resizing when the iframe-content changes.

Is this possible anyway?

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it) may be hepful for you.

Comment: unfortunately it isn't - it's all about resizing onload which works fine. my problem is to trigger the resizing from inside the iframe.

Comment: Quite simple and working solution ist this: http://codecopy.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/ghost-iframe-crossdomain-iframe-resize/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this library instead. It uses mutationObserver in the iFrame to pick up changes to the content.

**https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer**