# iframe auto height adjust not working

Tags: cakephp, iframe

I am using the cakephp framework, and on my site i sell wordpress themes. When any user click on demos it take the user demo page where they can see demos of that theme. I am using i frame for showing demos. But the problem is that the height of the iframe is not auto adjust. The error which occur is

Permission dined

The demos theme is in same destination where whole project. But now i want that the iframe work for both weather it is on same place or out site the site.

My site URL is: http://www.wplegion.com/
And the path where all my demos are showing is: http://www.wplegion.com/themes/demo/8

Comment: I tried many solution which is provide over here, but no one is working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Comment: also note that you cannot adjust height across domains due to the same origin policy.