# Fit Iframe height to its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is there a way to fit height of iframe to it's content? Would you show me how to do it?
I tried searching and trying out the codes on the net but no luck

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta NAME="Description" content="Communigate Technologies" />
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="pragma" content="no-cache" />

<title></title>

</head>

<body>
    <div align="center" style="z-index:1;">
    <?php include 'header.html' ?>

        <iframe align=top width=800px src="aboutus1.php" frameborder=1 border=0 framespacing=0 SCROLLING=no id="bodyframeid" name="bodyframename"></iframe>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it?rq=1

Comment: I studied that link and tried the script but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: aboutus1.php is a file, not a video or image that we can get its height and fix it to that. I guess you will have to fix it to a fixed height or may be 100%.

Answer (score 7):

Since we are in the age of CSS3, you can do this by using viewport units. These units allow you to specify sizes in terms of percentages of the viewport width and viewport height. This is the user's viewport, also known as screen. However, in all major browsers I've tried it, if you put an iframe inside a div, which is inside another div and positioned relative, the viewport units are relative to this div. And since 100 viewport height units mean 100% height, you can do like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="wrapper" style="position:relative">
        <iframe style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:100%;height:100vh;" src="http://anydomain.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I find this to be the best solution possible, since it is **cross-domain**, and displays exactly like you want it without any javascript or other complex stuff.

And most importantly, it works on all browsers, even mobile ones (tested on android and iphone)!

Comment: Absolutely the best solution here.  The cross-domain thing is a great bonus as well as the fact that is way way cleaner than the javacript option and more maintainable.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
  document.getElementById("iframename").height = (document.getElementById("iframename").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight) + "px";
```

Sometimes this didn't work but I noticed it was because the page of the iframe wasn't completelly rendered.
    In this case, and I never noticed any further problem, put the instruction inside:

```
 setTimeout(function (){ - here - }, 100)
```

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same origin for document and iframe content (and in your example, you have) you can run from your main document:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('my-iframe')
var content = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('content')
var height = content.offsetHeight + 15 //add something to support paddings etc.
iframe.style.height = height + 'px'
var width = content.offsetWidth + 15
iframe.style.width = width + 'px'
```

But inspect the size of your 'content' element you adapt to, because often the element is much greater than the visible content.