# Dynamic height in an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, dynamic, height

I have this website: http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/index/forum/0-14
It can be seen that under the iframed forum there is a huge space, I made it so I can display as much as I can while navigating but, is there any way i can make the height adjust after each page inside is loaded?

Code:

```
<iframe 
style="-moz-border-radius:10px; 
       -webkit-border-radius:10px; 
       border-radius:10px" 
height="4800" width="900" 
frameborder="0" src="http://thc-racing.forumotion.co.uk/"></iframe>
```

I have access to CSS and Scripts on the forum.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question at [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it) where you could use the code provided and modify it to adjust width and height with your own constant values, instead of auto-adjusting as the code provided in the accepted answer does.

Comment: it doesn't work, the iframe does not have constant values, it always changes