# Can't Access Parent-document from Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

I have a main page for navigating to other 3 pages in an **`iframe`**

Main page: **1.html**

Other 3 pages: **one.html**, **two.html**, **3.html**.

## Code

### 1.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
           <ul>
             <li style="float:left; margin:20px;"><a href="One.html" target="target">One</a></li>
             <li style="float:left; margin:30px;"><a href="Two.html" target="target">Two</a></li>
             <li style="float:left; margin:50px;"><a href="Three.html" target="target">Three</a></li>
           </ul>
           <iframe id="target"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### one.html

```
<html>
    <body onload="try{alert(parent.location.href);} catch(e){alert(e);}">
        1.html.
    </body>
</html>
```

But there is a problem showing the location of the `parent`-document. It's giving an alert message as follws:

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Can anyone please explain the meaning of the terms used in the message in the context of this error or simply why this happend???

### N.B.: No Server Used

Comment: That's probably your issue. If you read the file from disk I guess origin is null? Depending on the browser you could probably launch it with some options to ignore the same origin policy.

Comment: @plalx if I access a file from my own local file-system whats the matter of security??? Can you please explain.

Comment: You said you could access the other frame, have you tried reading it's properties?

Comment: @plalx, Sorry. Just now I noted that I can only access the current frame using the syntax `parent.frames['id']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome rather strictly assumes that there is no connection between local files.

On a Mac you can start Chrome from the terminal like this:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

and it will work, but the best thing would be to use a webserver.

Comment: Yes. Other browsers may handle it differently.

Comment: Tim, Thanx. **This worked in IE9**. Thanx for this very relevant info.