# Resize iframe to loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to load content in the iframe and make it resize its height according to the content. All the pages are in the same domain. I tried some scripts I found, but nothing worked. Most of the times, it just opens the loaded content in a new tab.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>index</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="nav"><a href="home.html">Home</a> <a href="the_band.html">The Band</a>
  <a href="News.html">News</a> <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> 
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div> <div id="content"></div>
  <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div#header {
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
}
div#nav {
    font-family: MgSouvenirLight;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: #FF0;
    top: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-variant: normal;
}
div#footer {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
 }
#frame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    bottom: 40px;
    width: 800px;
    border: none;
    left: 120px;
    height: auto;
}
a:link {
    font-family: MgSouvenirLight;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: #FF0;
}
a:visited {
    font-family: MgSouvenirLight;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: #FF0;
}
a:hover {
    font-family: MgSouvenirLight;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #FC0;
}
```

Comment: You can try looking at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Comment: @Stefan, I tried that (removing the newwidth lines), but it loads the content in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to get the height after iframe is loaded , and change it with jquery

```
     $('iframe').load(function() {
        setTimeout(iResize, 50);
        // Safari and Opera need a kick-start.
        var iSource = document.getElementById('your-iframe-id').src;
        document.getElementById('your-iframe-id').src = '';
        document.getElementById('your-iframe-id').src = iSource;
     });
     function iResize() {
        document.getElementById('your-iframe-id').style.height = 
        document.getElementById('your-iframe-id').contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
     }
```