# How to resize iframe according to in page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have drag and drop multiple files upload in `iframe`. This page is extend downward for not in iframe. I gived iframe `height:auto` but this is not working. I want, when the number of files increases, iframe should extend downwards with page in frame.

Here is my code:

```
<iframe src="dosya_up/index.php?"> </iframe>
```

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Comment: added invisible code

Comment: I read this. But this code working onLoad, i don't want onLoad. I want it to work every time a change is made.