# Full page height using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jquery-plugins

I have to set the height of the iframe based on the html content height. I am not able to find the exact height of the html content. i tried

```
alert($(document).height());
```

it is giving me 6214 and `$(windows).height()` just gives the height of viewpoint. Some of my pages are very long with scroll bar and some page doesnot have scroll bar. I want to get the exact height of the pages with or without scrollers so that i can set to the iframe. Please help me in this issue .

Thanks

Comment: <iframe name="report" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

Comment: why don't you just let the height undefined? it should work alone...

Comment: yes i tried this but it is not giving me correct height if the page is too long

Comment: how can i get the full page height

Comment: check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(document).height() will return you the exact height of your document i.e. your page.

If you want to get the content height use $(body).height().

Comment: using $(document).height() i am getting 6214 for all the pages

Comment: @OwaisAhmed Please check the other solution i have attached. I guess this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using `offsetHeight`

```
iframe.height = (iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight) + "px";
```