# iframe height issue when rendering dynamic report

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a iframe which fill with ssrs report dynamically so when report is fetched iframe is not displaying based on the report height.It even doesn't show scroll when iframe set to 100%. how to get the height of the iframe dynamically

Below is the iframe I use

Answer (score 0):

Maybe duplicate of [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

```
<script type="application/javascript">

function resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame ) {

    iFrame.width  = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentReady', function(e) {

    var iFrame = document.getElementById( 'iFrame1' );
    resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame );

    // or, to resize all iframes:
    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
    for( var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        resizeIFrameToFitContent( iframes[i] );
    }
} );

</script>

<iframe src="yoursource.html" id="iFrame1"></iframe>
```

Comment: If you think a question is a duplicate, flag it for closing.

Comment: Hi technico.i tried with your solution but i got access denied exception when i am trying to access contentwindow of a iframe

Comment: I'm confident about the fact you did change the iframe src value to fit your need. So this issue may come from the [domain origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe), which disable the possibility to acces the iframe content DOM, if the domain name don't match between main page and iframe page.