# iFrame height detection returns incorrect heights

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe with elements in it and I'm trying to resize the iframe to match its content. When I inspect the iframe, I can see the body has a height of `577px`, but when I access the height in Javascript, I receive `250px`.

Here is the code I'm using to get the height of the iframe:

```
function getHeight(el) {
  const {clientHeight, outerHeight, innerHeight, offsetHeight} = el;
  return clientHeight || outerHeight || innerHeight || offsetHeight;
}

// called on iframe's onload event
function onIframeLoad() {
  var iFrame = document.getElementById('advertFrame');
  if(iFrame) {
    var heightContainer = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body;
    var height = getHeight(heightContainer) + 'px';
    iFrame.height = height;
    iFrame.style.height = height;
  }
}
```

Comment: You might get the initial height of Iframe  immediately after page load without waiting for Iframe content to be loaded.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour But my intention is to know how tall the iframe's content is.  If I don't wait for the content, how could I tell how tall the content is going to be?

Comment: Perhaps the answer(s) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/819416/215552) will help you? You're not the first person who's wanted to make an iframe match its content's height...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the content of iframe to be loaded and then get its height. Jquery has a built in **"ready"** function to check if the iframe content are loaded. Please note that the **"ready"** refers to the load of source html code not the complete content of images and media. So you have to set initial height for images and other content those have changes in their height after complete loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#advertFrame').ready(function() {
      this.style.height =
      this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
  });
})
```

check the following example for a iframe load test: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrFzF/

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code with some description.