# How to change the size of this iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to embed this `iframe` into my webpage:

```
<iframe height="600px" width="600px" src="https://ionicabizau.github.io/github-profile-languages/api.html?damienAllonsius" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**EDIT**

I get this cool result but unfortunately the `iframe` is too big.
[image: Big iframe]

So how can I rescale it ? Let's say I want it 50% smaller.

When I change attributes `height` and `width` from `600` to `300`, I get this result
[image]

How can I fix that ? Changing the width and heigh with a CSS class does not change the result. Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it contains your answer. The answer with six upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply CSS properties `transform` and `transform-origin` to the `iframe`:

- `transform` will change the size of the whole `DOM object` tree (Also font size and so on)
- `transform-origin` will specify that the resize should start from `top left`. Otherwise, it would resize from the center and the resized `iframe` would flow in the middle.

  ```css
  #frame {
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <iframe id="frame" src="http://google.at" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  ```

Comment: Sorry but your answer produces the same problem as changing `height` and `width` attribute in the `iframe`. See the bottom of my webpage: https://damienallonsius.github.io/

Comment: So what is your actual problem then? Your question was "how to resize an iframe". Here you have the answer to that. If that was not your question, please try to reform your question so that I understand what you want to know. @dallonsi

Comment: I have just seen your update. I have updated my answer. Try it with transform. @dallonsi

Comment: Perfect !! Thanks

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. @dallonsi

Answer (score 1):

You may take one div and try to put `iframe` inside that div.

Apply `width:50%` to newly created div.

```css
.container-wrapper {
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can use the height and width attributes to specify the size of the iframe:</p>

<div class="container-wrapper">
  <iframe src="https://ionicabizau.github.io/github-profile-languages/" height="100%" width="100%">
  </iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Your iframe content should be responsive enough to display.

Comment: Sorry but your answer produces the same problem as changing `height` and `width` attribute in the `iframe`. See the bottom of my webpage: https://damienallonsius.github.io/