# Add iframe from different domain to Wordpress without scroll and 100% height

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to add an iframe to WordPress without scroll and not knowing the height.

What I have so far is: `<iframe src="[url from different domain]" scrolling="no" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>`

Unfortunately, this makes the iframe very small in height and only displays the first part.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31513163/4470542), I've also tried adding the following inline JS: `onload='javascript:(function(o){o.style.height=o.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+"px";}(this));'` but it gives a cross domain permission error.

I've tried adding inside DIVs and with other CSS attributes, but nothing works. The only way is to add a fixed height, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Hi! Can you post the URL to inspect?

Comment: If the iframe content is loaded from the same domain you can use the techniques shown in the duplicate question. If it is loaded from a different domain, there is nothing you can do other than set a fixed height.

Comment: @Turnip the iframe is from a different domain. I guess you're correct..