# Resize the iframe to fit to content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, iframe

I'm trying to display some dynamic HTML in the iframe, iframe size will be fixed in and the size of content should be fit to content in iframe,

if I'm using the transformation  i can not able to remove the extra wide space after the i frame.

```css
.scaled-frame { 
    width: 500px; 
      border: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
}

.scaled-frame {
    /*zoom: 0.51;*/
    -moz-transform: scale(0.55);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.55);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.55);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .scaled-frame  { zoom: 0.55;  }
}


/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.scaled-frame::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.scaled-frame {
      -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
      scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<template v-if="template_html">
    <iframe id="iFrame1" name="" :srcdoc="template_html" width="100%" style="height: 230em" allowfullscreen="true"/>
</template>
```

note: **template_html** is HTML string  i got form sever response.

any suggestions/guidance will appreciably

Comment: Possible duplicate? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Comment: Heya. a little bit confused by your question. You want the content within the iframe to fit the height and width of the iframe; it should be as simple as setting it's width and height to 100%. You're referencing a css class that you're not using in your html - '.scaled-frame' - I assume this is a wrapper that you're bringing in from template_html?

Comment: yes exactly i use it as wrapper , it scale down  the size of the my dynamic html but  i have lot of empty space which i have to  remove