# Blazor - .NET 5 : having iframes resized automatically

Tags: javascript, iframe, blazor, .net-5

I created an ASP.NET core project, with .NET 5, and it contains iFrames whose src attribute referencing an SSRS report:

```
<iframe src=@($"http://localhost/MyReportSvc?param1=...") scrolling="no" style="width:625px;height:100%" frameborder="0" />
```

but the content is dynamic and the iframe height changes depending of the URL parameters.

Please tell me if there exists a way (surely in javascript) to have the height set automatically depending of the content' height.

thank you

plz note : I found this : [related page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it), but I can't make it work in my blazor project. I hope it's not a cache problem.
Can somebody try this and tell me if it works in a blazor project with .NET5?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting to learn about [JsInterop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Also note that Blazor can gain a reference to a specific html element using `@ref`, which can then be passed to your JavaScript functions.

Once you've researched JsInterop and @ref, if you still have any questions, please come back with more specifics, and I'm sure we can get you sorted out. :D

Comment: I already used JSInterop, but with DOM searches, maybe I should use `@ref` as you suggested. I will try and tell you if it works.

Comment: @ref just gives you a reference you can pass to JavaScript.  You can also just use JavaScript like normal-- searching for elements by class, etc.  In fact, I don't think you even need to use JsInterop at all-- I believe if your script loads on window events, it will run just by including it.