# How to set screen resolution of iframe window?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am loading a 3rd party url in my site. The issue is content of the site is larger than expected.
Due to cross origin restriction, overriding of CSS is not possible.
Is it possible to change the resolution of the iframe window?

Comment: I hope this answer can help you with your doubt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Comment: @Maleficient Thanks for the link. Unfortunately iframe element size is not the issue. Its already set at 95vh. I need the content to be shrinked which can be achieved in larger screen. So I was wondering if its possible to set that explicitly for the iframe window.