# How to remove only the horizontal scroll from iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an input tag where people can use either images or pdf, and I want to display that document using iframe but it add both horizontal and vertical scroll to the document, whereas I would like the document width to fit to the iframe width and keep a scroll for vertical axis. Somewhat like a css property contain for background images.

```css
#div-test-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r');
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#iframe-test-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-test-img"></div>
<iframe id="iframe-test-img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r">
```

I want iframe to display similar to div, the same should be working with pdf's.
If possible please answer with an example of both image and pdf.
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Comment: @Josh The solution you gave explains how width of iframe can be changed whereas I want to change the size of content inside iframe.

Comment: Is the image just an example or do you want to show other websites on your page?

Comment: I want to use images and pdf's from my firebase storage, no other content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use images and pdfs you can do it like that:

```css
#div-test-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r');
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#test-img {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#iframe-pdf {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-test-img"></div>
<img id="test-img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r">
<iframe id="iframe-pdf" src="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"></iframe>
```