# How can I set the height of the iframe equal to website shown in it?

Tags: html, css, iframe, height, responsive

I'm trying to embed an external website into a page of mine with `<iframe src="http://...>`, I'm setting the width with a simple CSS rule, but **I want to set the height equal to the height of the website shown in the iframe**, how can I do it?

The website shown is an e-shop, the iframe shows a page with some products, I want that the iframe height grows when the page grows. If the page shown height is `2000px`, the iframe height will be `2000px`, if the screen width is smaller and the page shown height becomes `3400px`, the iframe height will become `3400px`, etc...

There is a way to do this?

Comment: There's an answer already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using CSS. Make a ruleset for `iframe`s and adding a declaration: `height: 100%`

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this on the ruleset for iframe:

```css
height: 100% !important;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work, it sets the iframe's height 100% of the parent div. It is not what i need. I need the iframe to follow the website in it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `vh` unit:

```css
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: `vh` is a unit for viewport height, not for the height of the document embeded.