# How do you embed HTML into HTML (and automatically resize)?

Tags: html, css, iframe

How do you embed HTML into HTML (and automatically resize)?

I tried using the [Inline Frame element (iframe)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) tag; but the iframe remains the default size—because of the default height and width settings. Further, I tried manipulating the [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) attribute; but again the iframe remains the same default size.

I know I can manually set the height and width attributes; but I like the way other HTML elements automatically resize and I want my iframe to "insert HTML; but then sorta get out of the way and just act like other HTML"—that is, make example 2 look like example 1—see screenshot.

Note: I don't *need to* use iframe; but I tried using iframe since the [HTML  Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_embed.asp) W3 Schools page suggested to do so.

For reference, I included my two index.html and note.html local files and a screenshot.

1. index.html

   ```html
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <style type="text/css">
   table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
   }
   </style>
   <title>iframe experiment</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h3>Example 1: Duplicated note</h3>
   <p>In the following example I duplicate my note 3 times. Notice how the HTML sizes as expected.</p>
   <p>Consider the following note:</p>
   <p>Note: This is a note.</p>
   <p>Consider the same note in a list:</p>
   <ol>
    <li><p>Note: This is a note.</p></li>
   </ol>
   <p>Consider the same note in a table:</p>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Note: This is a note.</p></td>
    </tr>
   </table>

   <h3>Example 2: Inline frame note</h3>
   <p>In the following example I embed my note 3 times with the <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe"><em>Inline Frame element (iframe)</em></a>. Notice how the inline frame looks wonky because of the default height and width.</p>
   <p>Consider the following note:</p>
   <iframe src="note.html"></iframe>
   <p>Consider the same note in a list:</p>
   <ol>
    <li><iframe src="note.html"></iframe></li>
   </ol>
   <p>Consider the same note in a table:</p>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><iframe src="note.html" style="object-fit:none;"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. note.html

   ```html
   <p>Note: This is a note.</p>
   ```
3. Screenshot

   [image: wonky iframe]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adjust width and height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

An `iframe` in HTML document 1 lets you include HTML document 2 using just its URL, but the size of the `iframe` is determined by document 1, not document 2. You can work around this using the Javascript trickery described in the article linked by @SteffenAndreasKloster in the comments.

Another method would be to write some Javascript in document 1 to [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the contents of document 2 as a string and then use [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to insert that into document 1. This effectively merges document 2 into document 1 so it “will just act like other HTML”.

Comment: In my example, I control _note.html_; but how do I declare something like _make note.html regular size_?

Comment: I don't follow. What do you mean by "regular size"? Are you talking about the size of the iframe, or the size of the text of note.html inside the iframe?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I mixed up your document 1 and 2—I thought my _note.html_ was 1; but it's actually 2. I'll try to re-read that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it question; but the ASP stuff looks distracting.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<iframe 
    src="note.html" 
    width="600" 
    height="400" 
    frameborder="0" 
    allowfullscreen 
    style="object-fit:none;">
</iframe>
```